# Google ads don't show on my website

Tags: javascript, html, ads, adsense

My Google advertisements aren't showing on my HTML homepage - instead there's a blank box.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

And this is what the code looks like:

```html
<div class="advertising margin-bottom" align="center">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:265px;height:600px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-7557573862902525"
         data-ad-slot="6854013507"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script> 
</div>
```

Comment: `http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com...`

Comment: Still blank even after changing the src, other suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser dev console?

Comment: Yep, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()" for the ad frames

Comment: https://www.shoutmeloud.com/adsense-403-forbidden-error.html#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason ads aren't being displayed is because your domain is **forbidden** (with error code 403).

This happens because AdSense does not want to display ads on your domain, either because of something you did that violated [AdSense policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en) or something the previous domain owner did.

> Policy specialists disable ad serving to a page or site when it’s found to be in violation of program policies

If it was something the previous domain owner did and your implementation of the site is in compliance then you can try and request that ad serving be reinstated.

To see information on how to do that:

1. [Sign in to your AdSense account](http://www.google.com/adsense).
2. In the left navigation panel, click **Settings**.
3. Click **Policy center**.

There's no guarantee that ad serving will be reinstated so in the future if you plan to buy a domain name and use it with AdSense you should check to see if AdSense has been disabled on it.

To verify if your domain is blocked or not: Use [the Adsense Sandox tool](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.labnol.org%2Fgoogle-adsense-sandbox%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEpQ5vNIf6I8cCmSsztBNOUMIH80w), and put in your sites' URL. If no ads show up (like they don't for your url) it means the domain is blocked.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I also don't have any violations. I'll send a ticket to the google support anyways

Comment: What is your domain name ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I didn't include the script in the head so they can verify my site. I'll have to wait some days to see if it's fixed or not